# Programming language with multiple roots

Tags: python, programming-languages, octave, julia, complex-numbers

The answer to 2^(-1/3) are three roots:

0.79370, -0.39685-0.68736i and 0.39685+0.68736i (approximately)

See the correct answer at [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E%28-1%2F3%29).

I know several languages that supports complex numbers, but they all only return the first of the three results:

Python:

```
>>> complex(2,0)**(-1/3)
(0.7937005259840998-0j)
```

Octave:

```
>> (2+0i)^(-1/3)
ans = 0.79370
```

Julia:

```
julia> complex(2,0)^(-1/3)
0.7937005259840998 + 0.0im
```

What I'm looking for is something along the lines of:

```
>> 2^(-1/3)
[0.79370+0i, -0.39685-0.68736i, 0.39685+0.68736i]
```

Is there a programming language (with a REPL) that will correctly return all three roots, without having to resort to any special modules or libraries, that also has an open source implementation available?

Comment: I know that [`sympy`](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) in python has the capabilities of doing this though I myself am not all too familiar with how

Comment: That's cool! I'm particularly interested in a language that can do this "out of the box", though. Updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: Probably Mathematica? It seems to have all sorts of stuff like this.

Comment: any math based language probably has it, [Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/roots.html) seems to have this function

Comment: Matlab first one i can think of.

Comment: Thanks, both Mathematica and Matlab can probably do this. Updated the question to reflect that I was looking for open source software. I should have been even more specific in the first place.

Comment: Oh, yeah, of course, just treating it as a special case of general polynomial root-finding and passing it to a function for that would do the job.

Comment: @Alexander: [Octave has `roots`, just like Matlab.](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Finding-Roots.html)

Comment: @user2357112 Yeah, but when entering 2^(-1/3), only one root is returned. Is there a language that will return all three?

Comment: @Alexander: Doubtful. If you make 2^(-1/3) give 3 results, then defining 2^-ln(3) gets weird. Also, if 1/3 is floating-point, then it's not exactly a third of 1, and you need to make hard choices about tolerances. This is better handled by a function explicitly designed to return the roots of an equation.

Comment: 2^-ln(3) is approximately 0.46696 according to Wolfram Alpha. Please explain what would get weird, I don't see it. And how would a function call make the hard choices any easier?

Comment: There is something very confusing about the way this question is phrased. 2^(-1/3) by itself is not an equation (or inequality) and so has no "solution" per se. However, 2^(-1/3) is a solution to the equation x^(-3) = 2, which is what OP really is asking. However, by convention in complex analysis, 2^(-1/3) refers only to the principal root, which in this case is real. It is understood that the other roots are related to 2^(-1/3) by powers of exp(-i 2pi/3).

Comment: Jiahao Chen, you are undoubtedly right about complex analysis. But when Wolfram Alpha gets it right, why can't also a REPL for a language that already supports both complex numbers and multiple return values also get it right?

Comment: My point is that 2^(-1/3), as the principal root, is a real number. The first thing that Wolfram Alpha returns is exactly this _single_ real number. Asking for all the roots of x^-3 = 2 is a different question, one answered by `roots`, which Wolfram Alpha is pointing to you as related information. So you are not being precise by saying "Wolfram Alpha gets it right" - it gets it right only because it's trying to second-guess you and you read the part of the output that is the answer that you wanted, which is actually the answer to a different question.

Comment: I see. Thank you for explaining.

Comment: What gets weird? Well, why do you think that 2^-ln(3) having only one solution and 2^(-1/3) having 3 makes sense, besides that Wolfram Alpha said so? Because -ln(3) is irrational? If you make x^y single-valued for irrational y and multi-valued for rational y, you run into all sorts of nasty problems, from "what floating-point numbers do we guess are meant to be irrational when all finite floating-point numbers are actually rational" to "how do we sanely deal with an output that could be either a number or a list when we don't know the rationality of y".

Comment: Part (1/2): Alexander, I can't be certain, but I suspect the issue is one of language design, and specifically revolves around type-stability. That is, if a programming language is to be fast, then the output types from a function need to be pre-determined based on the input types. In your case, you have a simple function: two floating point inputs, one put to the power of the other. If we input `2.0^(-1/2)`, then there are two roots. If we input `2.0^(-1/3)` there are three roots, and so on. If the behaviour you are after is that all roots are output from the function, then the

Comment: Part (2/2): language needs to do a *lot* of work every time the function is called in order to determine the output type. Therefore the function (and probably the whole language) will be very slow. If instead, the language uses the rule that only the first root is output, no matter what the inputs, then there is much less work needed to determine the output type (it'll either be a single floating point, or a single complex) and so the function (and language) will run much faster. This is why root-finding should (and usually will) be its own special-case function.

Comment: @ColinTBowers see my earlier comments about 2^(-3) being by convention _one_ of the solutions to x^-3 = 2. It is correct that 2^(-3) only evaluates to a single real number.

Comment: Things would get worse if you wanted the same behaviour for other
[multi-valued functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_function):
for instance, `log(1)` would no longer be a single number, `0`,
from the [principal branch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_branch) of the logarithm,
but the _infinite_ set, 2πiℤ,
containing all the solutions of `exp(z)=1`.

Comment: @Vincent Zoonekynd, I think that would be awesome! Some languages support infinite sets, like Haskell. Perhaps there is a theoretical possibility that a language could support this?

Comment: @JiahaoChen Ah yep, you're totally on the money there. I think I got a bit side-tracked - In my head I was trying to explain why `sqrt(4)` typically returns `2` in most languages, even though `-2` is an equally valid answer. But you're right, it doesn't really make sense to discuss that with respect to the roots of an expression that isn't even an equation...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As many comments explained, wanting a general purpose language to give by default the result from every branch of the complex root function is probably a tall order. But **Julia** allows specializing/overloading operators very naturally (as even the out-of-the-box implementation is often written in Julia). Specifically:

```
using Roots,Polynomials  # Might need to Pkg.add("Roots") first
import Base: ^

^{T<:AbstractFloat}(b::T, r::Rational{Int64}) =
    roots(poly([0])^r.den - b^abs(r.num)).^sign(r.num)
```

And now when trying to raise a float to a rational power:

```
julia> 2.0^(-1//3)
3-element Array{Complex{Float64},1}:
 -0.39685-0.687365im
 -0.39685+0.687365im
 0.793701-0.0im
```

Note that specializing the definition of `^` to rational exponents solves the rounding problem mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to solve for all of the roots of *b*<sup>1/*n*</sup> via the roots the polynomial *x*<sup>*n*</sup> - *b* with Matlab's [`roots`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/roots.html) or Octave's [`roots`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Finding-Roots.html):

```
b = 2;
n = -3; % for b^(1/n)
c = [1 zeros(1,abs(n)-1) -b];
r = roots(c).^sign(n);
```

which returns

```
r =

 -0.396850262992050 - 0.687364818499301i
 -0.396850262992050 + 0.687364818499301i
  0.793700525984100 + 0.000000000000000i
```

Alternatively, using [roots of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity) (not sure how numerically robust this is):

```
b = 2;
n = -3;
n0 = abs(n);
r0 = b^(1/n0);
w = exp(2*pi*1i/n0);
r = (r0*w.^(0:n0-1).').^sign(n)
```

Or using Matlab's Symbolic Math toolbox:

```
b = 2;
n = -3;
c = [1 zeros(1,abs(n)-1) -b];
r = solve(poly2sym(c)).^sign(n)
```

which returns:

```
r =

                           2^(2/3)/2
  2^(2/3)/(2*((3^(1/2)*1i)/2 - 1/2))
 -2^(2/3)/(2*((3^(1/2)*1i)/2 + 1/2))
```

In certain cases you might also find [`nthroot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nthroot.html) helpful ([Octave documentation](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/nthroot.html)).

Comment: Yes, but Octave lacks the two other answers when typing in 2^(-1/3).

Comment: You're never going to get all of the roots by just typing `2^(-1/3)` in any language. My code should work fine in Octave.

Comment: If you are sure that there exists no such language, I will accept that as the answer. I am more interested in language design than the actual roots.